Редирект для SPA, исключая папку api
Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой, которую не могу побороть 2 день :(
Мне нужно перенаправить все запросы на index.html (с сохранением адреса для распознавания url уже через index.html), кроме запросов на api/
Вот структура папок на хостинге:

public_html (корневой каталог сайта)

index.html (SPA сдинамическими url)
api (это папка, в которой php скрипты как бэкэнд)



Решил проблему используя 2 файла .htaccess.
Первый файл находится в корне и перенаправляет все запросы на index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html

Второй файл .htaccess лежит в папке api. Он пустой и нужен для того, чтоб отменить действие файла, описанного выше! Если кто-то знает как решить это всё одним файлом - пишите. Буду рад.
